# "Mesh Boolean" output is unstable with driver

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

[image]

I'm using the version 3.0.1.

When I added a driver in any geometry nodes (e.g. `#frame`), I found that the result of "Mesh Boolean" node changes in every frames, even though the operated meshes don't depends on frame or any drivers.
It seems only changing the order of the vertices which generated on Boolean operation.

Is there any way to avoid this phenomenon?

Comment: i don't know whether this is still valid, but a few month ago the advice of one of the developers to me was: don't use the mesh boolean operator because it is slow and unstable. Use delete geometry instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's interesting. But I cannot imagine how the Delete node will replace the Boolean operation.

Comment: If you have a „simple“ Boolean operation with a cube - it is simple vector math operation. Of course it is another case with more complicated geometry. But even there - it is „just math“ - but more complicated.

Comment: Just think of this: if you have a working function which returns a Boolean if a point is in a geometry or not - then you could build a Boolean modifier with this function.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Just downloaded Blender 3.0.1 2022-01-25 17:19 hash dc2d180118171 Windows, geonodes setup: https://i.imgur.com/yW0nnsc.png , when playing the animation, nothing changes... BTW, getting an internal error when uploading to blend-exchange...

Comment: Thanks Markus for your testing.
Yes, while playing the animation I also cannot see any changes in the Viewer . When I'm stepping frame to frame by arrow keys, or using the index attribute of vertices in the Boolean mesh, this phenomenon is seen.
But, I should have tried also the vanilla 3.0 w/o any Addons. I'll try that.

Comment: I also don't see any change when stepping frame by frame using left/right arrow keys.

Comment: I installed the vanilla environment, and I could reproduce it in it too.

Don't you see only the vertices with the smaller indices?
It occurs on the vertices with the larger indices those it might be generated by Boolean node.

Comment: And, wow, it's not seen in the 3.1.0-beta !